# using db4o database with gridview control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, db4o

I have a db4o database which i want to use with asp.net web application and i want to databind data from db4o database. How can i do that ?

I'm using VS2008/asp.net with c#

Help me out

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like db4o has [Linq](http://developer.db4o.com/Blogs/Product/tabid/167/entryid/87/Default.aspx) support.  I also found this article [An introduction to LINQ for db4o](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/LINQ_for_db4o.aspx?q=ado.net%20db4o) on CodeProject on how to use the Linq to db4o.  You'll probably want to read the whole thing but if you want to go directly to the demos, they are about half way down the page.

There are also some more [examples](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/net20/Content/basics/querying/linq.htm) in their documentation, including a [*basic operations (storing, updating, querying and deleting objects)*](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/net20/Content/basics.htm) example.

Answer (score 0):

The db4o `container.Query<T>()` method returns a Db4objects.Db4o.Internal.Query.GenericObjectSetFacade   object, which you can not directly put into a DataGrid. I'm assumig that also happens with a GridView.

Try using Linq extension method `ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)` :

```
using System.Linq;
/*...*/
IList<MyClass> db4oList = container.Query<MyClass>();
grid.DataSource = db4oList.ToList();
```